# Accessing FRIENDS' basic information

Tags: api, permissions, facebook-fql

I'm trying to access basic information from a FRIEND page via FQL:

`SELECT name, status, locale FROM user WHERE uid = 11111111`

I can get the name and locale, but I can't see their status. If I go to their page, I can see their status, so I should have access to it via the FQL api too, shouldn't I?

Or, do I have to request *every* user for user_status (or friends_status?) when next they visit the page? This is definitely my stumbling block.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what permissions you have for your access token, lint it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint.

To see a friend's status, the user will need to grant `friends_status` per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions.

If you find that you don't have those permissions for that user, send them to FB.login() with the `scope` parameter set to the permissions you require.

Comment: oh, ok, so there's no chance in h377 to understand our audience, just our page consumption. too bad. I guess that's what all the privacy fuss has been all about. what a shame, Facebook could have been useful.

Comment: I'm actually really surprised, considering that I can actually *go* to a friended page and see their data, but I can't access it through the API. Man of the Year? I like to think not.

Comment: With the API, its a whole different story than with the UI. Remember, the more secure you make something, the more difficult it will be to implement. Also, whether or not you agree with Facebook's decisions, doesn't invalidate my answer to your question.